# How to get features in Openlayers vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2, features

What is the exact API to get all features in a vector layer in OpenLayers? Suppose I have the "map" object, within which is a "Vector Layer": how can I obtain features in the layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's not part of the vector layer api [OpenLayers -Vector-js.html](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html).

`vector_layer.features` should do the trick, though.  This is an array maintained by the layer, which saves references to each geometry it contains.

I don't know if you use the Firefox add-on called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), but among other things, it makes interrogating the internals of javascript objects a breeze.

Comment: Just a note, it is part of the API, so layer.features is the right to get at them.   http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.features

Comment: Yes, I also noted that. But it seems that the property `features` can only be obtained from `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector`, while the object `map` only has access to `OpenLayer.Layer`. The former is inherited from the latter. Then how can I get `OpenLayer.Layer.Vector`?

Comment: if you use c#or java, you need to do a cast, but here you can use use javascript magic :)
if (layer.features) {
//do stuff
}

Comment: Since `vector_layer.features` is somewhat internal we ended up extending the Vector layer and override the add method to keep a reference to added features.